# Allowing user to write how many inputs does he want to put in

Tags: javascript, node.js, prompt, readline

A few days ago I wanted to participate in a coding challenge but I really struggled with an essential task and that´s making inputs. My code Should work like this:

The user should input number *T*, then he should write *T-times*, *number N*, and on the next row *N (random) numbers*. Input and output tables may look like this.

T
N
(numbers)

**For example:**
2 (T)
4 (first N)
1 2 5 3 (four numbers because the first N is 4)
4 (second N)
4 4 6 8 (three numbers because the second N is 4)

And then code will take this and process it into an output but that´s not so problematic...

I tried to code this in javascript (with node.js and deadline or prompt) and python but I failed with both. Here you can see the code that I used:

```
const prompt = require("prompt");
let stepT = 0;
let stepN = 0;

prompt.start();
prompt.get(["T"], function (err, T) {
    reqN(T.T);
});

const reqN = T => {
    prompt.get(["N"], (err, N) => {
        console.log("I got N");
        let cisla = reqNumbers(T);
        if (++stepT < T) reqN(T);
        else stepT = 0;
    });
};

const reqNumbers = T => {
    prompt.get(["numbers"], (err, num) => {
        console.log("I got numbers");
        let cisla = num.numbers.split(" ");
        console.log(cisla);
        if (++stepN < T) reqNumbers(T);
        else stepN = 0;
        return cisla;
    });
};
```

(this code is using Javascript and node.js with prompt)

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('', (count) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {   rl.question('', (answer) => {
            console.log(answer);
        });
    };
  rl.close();
});
```

(in this code I tried to use readline in a for loop so that I could allow the user to say how many inputs does he want to put.)

Both failed. And while the readline one is failing to do anything, the prompt-y one does this:
[First, it wants T, then it wants N, that´s all alright. But then it should want numbers from me(as I wrote in the example) but it wants the second N and what is fascinating, when I should write the second N it looks like I can´t write one character at the time but only TWO! It looks like there are two prompts opened. And then it wants numbers where I again, can only write two characters at the time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGXvu.png)

This is not the first time I have this problem so that´s why I decided to write here... If anyone can help I would really be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get user input is with `prompt-sync`:

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();

let T = Number(prompt('Enter T'));

for (let i = 0; i < T; i++) {
    let N = Number(prompt('Enter N'));
    let numbers = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < N; j++)
        numbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
    console.log(...numbers);
}
```